# OpenCV : How to discard a channel in an image?

Tags: opencv

I have an HLS image and I want to discard the L channel to create a two channels image. Is there a more elegant way than split and merge functions ?

Answer (score 0):

No, split and merge is the most elegant way to romove a channel.